# Activate Root on Mac OSX: No Editor in Directory Utility

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, root

I'm on OSX 10.6.8 and would like to enable the root user. I found [Apple's KB article](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1528), however this point

- Click the lock in the Directory Utility window.
- Enter an administrator account name and password, then click OK.
- Choose Enable Root User from the **Edit** menu.

is not possible, because there is no "Edit Menu" Icon! I'm logged in as admin, but I only see "Services" and "Search Policy". Repeat, I do **not** see the "Editor", it's just not there. What gives?

How it should be: Directory Utility
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's referring to the Edit *menu*, i.e. the thing along the top of the screen labeled "Edit". The "Directory Editor" icon isn't supposed to be there in 10.6 (it was added in 10.7), and the instructions don't refer to it.

Comment: Clarified the question. There is no "Edit Menu" icon, I just see the first two "Services" and "Search Policy".

Comment: Don't look in the window, look at the top of the screen. You should see: Apple Icon, Directory Utility, File, Edit, Window, Help.

Comment: Aaaaah. That makes a lot more sense and answers my questions.. sometimes we are so blind to the bleeding obvious :) Thanks a lot!